# What is the most common word used for 'idea'?

Tags: words, loanwords

Pretty sure I've mostly seen idea as アイデア

Does anyone know of other words used for 'idea' and if possible any example sentences and contexts where different words are used?

Comment: Examples: http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/idea

Answer (score 11):

Use **アイディア** (or アイデア) when it's replaceable with *resolution*, *suggestion*, etc. If you really want to avoid loanwords, you can use "(良い)考え".

> What shall we do? Do you have any *idea*?
> 何しよう?　何か**アイディア**ある?
>
> An *idea* is something that solves multiple problems at once. -- Shigeru Miyamoto
> [**アイデア**というのは複数の問題を一気に解決するものである](http://www.1101.com/iwata/2007-08-31.html) -- 宮本茂

Use **概念【がいねん】** (or 考え方) when it's replaceable with *concept*, *way of understanding it*, etc. コンセプト may also be a good translation, I think.

> The basic *idea* of Darwin's theory of evolution is that all species of organisms arise and develop through the natural selection ...
> ダーウィンの進化論の基本的な**考え方/概念/コンセプト**は、すべての生物種は自然淘汰を経て発生・発達し…

Use **イデア** when it refers to the [Plato's theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_Forms).

> According to the theory of *Ideas*, non-material abstract forms (or *ideas*), and not the material world of change known to us through sensation, possess the highest and most fundamental kind of reality.
> **イデア**論によれば、我々が感覚を通じて知っている変化する物質世界ではなく、非物質的・抽象的な形式、すなわち**イデア**が、最も重要かつ基礎的な実在である。

'Idea' in a sentence like this is very difficult to translate using a noun:

> Do you have any *idea* what I am talking about?
> 私が何を言っているのか**分かる**か? (or **理解している**か?)

Comment: Talking about more concrete ideas, such as plans, suggestions, way of going about something, etc. there's also 案, either in compounds relating to ideas (as illustrated here: [http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=idea+%E6%A1%88]), or standalone as in 優れた案、いい案, etc.

Comment: With 案, there's also 名案 :-)